# Datetime picker with default initial value (basic Html & Javascript only)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to have a datetime picker with default value *(Date.now)* but I am restricted javascript only (no jquery).

I managed to pull it off with a hack, **is there a better way to do this?**

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inputDate">
```

#### Javascript

```
var dateField = document.getElementById("inputDate");
var date = new Date();
dateField.setAttribute("type", "datetime-local");
dateField.setAttribute("value", date.toISOString().slice(0, 19));
```

I wonder if this works in all browsers, only tried it in Chrome.

Comment: 'All browsers'? IE4?  Netscape Navigator 3?

Comment: You know what I mean - Most popular browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a link that may be helpful for you. It shows you the browsers that accept the inputs with type "date".
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime
In order to make it more "crossbrowser", you should consider to use jQuery-UI datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It is really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The new input types to HTML5 are new, which makes them very restrictive and hard to use. They are hard to manipulate, style and customize.

I would use an html simple textbox with a "man-made" down arrow that you can click and populate your calendar (or whatever you would like to show). This can all be done with simple javascript and textBox.

I have a calendar datepicker pure javascript which I use over and  over again because I can make it do whatever I would like it to do.

Comment: Another down-side to these new input types(I just remembered) is the lack of cross-browser support.

Comment: Doesn't your calendar datepicker in js introduce some avoidable overhead to the application?

Comment: it's pure uncomplicated javascript. I don't think it needs too much to run. But then again, I'm only a beginner programmer with 3 years under my belt.